How to drill perspex
I have some Perspex sheets that have a coloured backing.  I need to drill a number of holes in them from the front (as that's the visible bit).
My first attempts with metal drill bits at low speed and high speed, resulted in blowouts at the back.  Even though I had them pressed hard against a bit of timber.
How should I drill the holes to avoid/reduce the blow-outs?

use 3 stage pre-drill

A diamond bit to grind the holes out, instead of drilling with bits that cuts by chipping.  Have not drilled those sheets but have cut them with a diamond saw blade.  Like cutting butter with a hot knife.

@crip659, you should make that an answer

@Traveler, on one hole I did try predrilling, but that made no difference.

How thick is the perspex?

I wanted confirmation of the other two answers as I did not have test pieces of Perspex.  I Googled again and found conflicting suggestions.  However, the key thing was that you need to cut vertically rather than horizontally.  I ended up using 4 drill bits, purely due to availability of sizes at the store.

First the fine bit to act as pilot (centre punch)
Next two are wood drill bits
Finally a Dremel bit (if it had been longer and pointier, I could have skipped a step).

The first hole had a slight push out as the dremel melted the plastic.  I went slower next times and the other 3 holes were perfect.


perpex is kind of rubbery, and as such tends to grab the drill bit,
this is undesirable,  to mitigate this:
ideally you want a pointy drill bit (like 90 degrees: 45 degrees each side)
Alternatively use a blunt drill bit or a nail and let the drill melt its way though.

I've had the best results drilling Perspex / acrylic by modifying the drill bit to have a zero rake angle.
Rake angle is the angle that the cutting edge of the drill bit makes with the surface that you are drilling. In an unmodified drill bit, that's the angle defined by the slope of the inside of the spiral helix.
To give the cutting edge a zero rake angle, take a fine file or a fine stone and grind a small flat inside the helix right there at the cutting edge. Maintain the zero degree angle by orienting the flat in line with the long axis of the drill bit. The flat only needs to be about 0.5 to 1mm on its face.

The idea is you don't want the cutting edge to auger into the plastic. You want it to scrape the surface of the plastic.
